# Does SharpSSH v1.1.1.13 support .Net framework 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, nullreferenceexception, sharpssh

I have been using this library with .Net framework 3.5 and it was working perfectly. Then I start a new project with .Net framework 4.5 and it stop working. It throws a null reference exception when connecting to an SFTP.

This is the exception stacktrace:

```
    Session.connect: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.jce.HMACMD5.update(Byte[] foo, Int32 s, Int32 l)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.read(Buffer buf)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.UserAuth.start(Session session)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.UserAuthNone.start(Session session)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect(Int32 connectTimeout)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect(Int32 connectTimeout)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.SshBase.Connect(Int32 tcpPort)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It is an old library, but its source code is available. You could try importing the source project into your solution, remove the DLL reference and add a reference to that project. Run your application in debug mode and have fun :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem wasn't with SharpSSH. It was with installation package. So yes, SharpSSH is compatible with .Net Framework 4.5.